# Is there a way to print two Java methods in two columns?

Tags: java, methods, printing, console, formatter

I'm making a Battleship game with two players and I have several classes. In my main class, I call the same method twice to print my board and the other players' boards. Is there a way to print both on the same lines but separated by some padding?

```
//Prints the board to the console
    public void printBoard(){ 
        int leftNum = 0;
        System.out.print("  ");
        for (int i = 0; i <= 14; i++) { //prints the numbers across the top of the board
            if (i < 10) { //checks to see how many spaces to print in between numbers
            System.out.print(i + "  ");
            } else {
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) { //prints numbers across side of the board as well as the symbols
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print("" + board[i][j] + "  ");
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the method in my Board class that I call for each board to print them.

Comment: Try with System.out.printf() look this article for reference https://www.baeldung.com/java-printstream-printf you can even accumulate the result to a String and print atlast.

Comment: So I tried to look at this way of doing it, but I cannot use this in the main method when Board1 and Board2 are different objects each calling the printBoard() method separately. Would I have to make a separate method in the Board class?

Comment: Yes, there's no good way to accomplish side-by-side display with the current `printBoard` method.  Once you call `System.out.print`, that output is sent to standard output and there's not an easy way to retrieve it.  You could e.g. append each line of output to an ArrayList and merge the lines of output from each board in the main method.

Comment: This is a great idea. I was going to try something like this tomorrow after thinking about it some more, thank you!